# Dictionary string formatting

Tags: python, string, dictionary, formatting

```
Pickaxes = {
 'adamant pickaxe': {'name': 'adamant pickaxe', 'cost': 150, 'sell': 100},
 'bronze pickaxe': {'name': 'bronze pickaxe', 'cost': 10, 'sell': 1},
 'dragon pickaxe': {'name': 'dragon pickaxe', 'cost': 666, 'sell': 333}}


def sell():
   global sell
   global money
   print "Your inventory", inventory
   selling = raw_input("\nWhich item in your inventory would you like to sell?: \n")
   if selling in inventory:
        if selling in Pickaxes:
           print "You have chosen the item", selling
           print "In return you will recieve %(sell)% Coins" % Pickaxes[selling]
           confirm = raw_input ("\nAre you sure you wish to sell the item\n")
           if confirm == "yes":
                i = inventory.index(selling)
                del inventory[i]
                money = money + Pickaxes[selling]["sell"]
                print "You now have", money, "Coins"
                time.sleep(2)
                raw_input("\nHit Enter to return to the menu\n")
                home()
```

The user will type what  they want to sell in the raw_input which will be checked against their inventory, if its in their inventory it will now check if it is in the Pickaxes DICTIONARY if it is, then i want to print something which will tell them how much their getting for that item  from the values in the dictionary.

For example the user types in `bronze pickaxe` in the raw_input, I want the print out to be: 
`print("For the item %s you will receive %s Coins") % (The name of the pickaxe chosen in the raw_input)(And the sell price within the dictionary).`

Comment: Neat project idea :-) Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes how do i format strings within a dictionary using their input within raw_input to identify what values to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for a quick and dirty hack into your code:

```
if selling in Pickaxes:

       confirm = raw_input ("Are you sure you wish to sell the item {} "
                 "for {} Coins? (y/n)\n>>".format(
                     selling,Pickaxes[selling]["sell"]))
       if confirm.lower() in ["yes","y"]:
            i = inventory.index(selling)
            del inventory[i]
            money = money + Pickaxes[selling]["sell"]
            print "You now have", money, "Coins"
            time.sleep(2)
            raw_input("\nHit Enter to return to the menu\n")
            home()
```

Comment: Brilliant exactly what i wanted! Thankyou very much

Comment: Be aware this is probably not the best way to do what you're trying to do. There are several other good answers to the questions you're asking down below. This will make your code work without refactoring, but once it works, MAKE IT BETTER.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to format your printed statement, but you're getting an error.

```
>>> name = "diamond pick"
>>> price = 999
>>> print("For the item %s you will receive %s Coins") % (name)(price)
For the item %s you will receive %s Coins
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Your syntax is a little off. The percent should go *inside* `print`'s parentheses, and the right hand side should be a single tuple.

```
>>> print("For the item %s you will receive %s Coins"% (name,price))
For the item diamond pick you will receive 999 Coins
```

In any case, you ought to use the shiny and new `format` method compared to the old and dusty percent style formatting.

```
>>> print("For the item {} you will receive {} Coins".format(name,price))
For the item diamond pick you will receive 999 Coins
```

Comment: Yes kevin thats the idea but i want to format from my dictionary, also i want the sell price to be recognised by what the user types into the raw_input and then printed out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. You can already access the price with `Pickaxes[selling]["sell"]`.

Comment: Yes thats not working for me within that print thats all i want to know is how to write that print statement correctly formatted etc..

Answer (score 0):

You could Try

```
>>> stmt = "For the item {0} you will receive %(sell)s Coins"

>>> raw_input("{0} {1}".format((stmt % Pickaxes[selling]).format(selling),
              'Please Confirm: (y/n):') )

For the item adamant pickaxe you will receive 100 Coins Please Confirm: (y/n):
```

While Integrating to the code:

```
  ## Your code before the if condition ##
  if selling in Pickaxes:

       stmt = "For the item {0} you will receive %(sell)s Coins"

       confirm = raw_input("{0} {1}".format((stmt % Pickaxes[selling]).format(selling),
                           "Please Confirm: (y/n):"))

       if confirm.lower().strip() == "y":
           ## rest of your code ##
```

Comment: if you were to add this to my code how would it be written :s im finding this abit confusing but i know this is what i want

Comment: @Ali, Please look the modification.

Comment: i've tried it i still don't understand, could you please fit it into my code. Sorry for the hassle